# How to display ng-repeat data with certain conditions - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, object

This is my json object response:

```
{
"draftType": "manualinput",
"senderdata": "123456789",
"senderName": "ifelse",
"message": "Hi",
"draftName": "Testing"
}
```

I am displaying this in UI using ng-repeat:

controllers.js:

```
$http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: '/api/getdraft'

}).then(function (response) {
   $scope.drafts = response.data;
}, function (response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

my code:

```
tr(ng-repeat='draft in drafts')
 td {{draft.draftName}}
 td {{draft.senderName}}
 td {{draft.message}}
```

But i need some condition, if my **draftType** object key have string called "manualinput" i want to display datas,

sometimes draftType will come as "contactinput",

so i dont want to display if my draftType is not equal to "manualinput".

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Use `ng-if="draft.draftType.includes('manualinput')"` inside `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Its working thanks it should be in answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **`ng-if`** with **`ng-repeat`**

CODE:

```
tr(ng-repeat='draft in drafts' ng-if="draft.draftType === 'manualinput'")
```

Comment: post full answer! it will helpful to me, this should be in comment section :)

Comment: i am typing from phone, it takes some time :P

Answer (score 2):

You can add ng-if with ng-repeat. please try with this.

```
tr(ng-repeat='draft in drafts') data-ng-if="draft.draftType === 'manualinput'"
 td {{draft.draftName}}
 td {{draft.senderName}}
 td {{draft.message}}
```